# Cognito ユーザープールの情報をlambda(python)で取得するには？

Tags: lambda, amazon-cognito

aws cognitoに登録されているユーザーの内指定の属性を持つユーザーのみにメールを送る実装を考えています。
ユーザープールにアクセスして、ユーザー情報を取得することはできましたが、カスタム属性に指定した値を取得することができません。

```
response = client.list_users(
  UserPoolId=USER_POOL_ID,
  AttributesToGet=['email'],
  Limit=LIMIT
)
```

カスタム属性のデータをもとにメール送信有無を決定しようとしていますので要件を満たせなくて困っております。カスタム属性に代わりユーザーグループを使おうかとも思っているのですが同様に取得する方法がわかりません。（Webで調べたのですがリファレンスがあまり出てこず、見つけられませんでした）
カスタム属性 または ユーザーグループ をlambda(python)より取得する方法をご存じの方は教えていただきたいです。できないという情報があればそれでもかまいません。
ご協力お願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cognito の API 仕様を確認したい場合は、SDK のドキュメントより、API のドキュメントの方が参考になると思います。

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html

質問中の

> カスタム属性に指定した値を取得することができません

については AttributesToGet に該当のカスタム属性も指定するか、AttributesToGet の指定自体を外してしまえばいいと思います。指定がなければ、全属性が返ってきます。この API だと前ユーザをリストアップしなければいけないため、ユーザをグループに入れた上で、ListUsersInGroup の API を入れると効率はいいと思います。